# Add Country/State Values in Android App

Tags: android

I want to add the countries and their corresponding States in android application locally, in such a way that when the user clicks on the country a dialog should come up and it should show a list of country names, and when the person selects a country, in the state dialog it should show the corresponding state names.

I have a list( in xml format ) for all the country and their states but i am unable to use them in my android app and also do not know the way how to use them.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

you can do like wheel demo like iphone default spinner,

I have a link which has the same concept like you want. but yes it has not been entered all the list of country and their state. but on that you can find the way how to get it.

http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

For Country and it's state detail you have to find out in google that any default methods provides to get all countries and their states or otherwise you have to add it manually add it by country wise I have the link that has list of country and it's states.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population

hope it will help you.

Comment: please give the reason for down vote. I am giving you the answer according to what I have found from the Google and S.O. but even if  it is not required by you and doesn't solve your problem then please tell me, I will definitely delete my answer.